# Setting value to an state of array of interface doesn't work, instead it's following the amount of { } in the [ ] in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs

So, i want to fetch data from API then putting the data on my DataTable. The thing i did is using a state as a variable so it can be dynamically changed any time. The problem is when i put empty array in the use state and calling the set function, it won't work, here is the example of the code :

```
const [moduleRows, setModuleRows] = React.useState([] as ModuleRow[]);
useEffect(() => {
    function getModule():Promise<Module[]> {
        return fetch('http://localhost:7071/api/module/').then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
            return res as Module[]
        })
    }
    getModule().then(module => {
        let tempModuleRows:ModuleRow[] = []
        for (let index = 0; index < module.length; index++) {
            tempModuleRows.push({
                no: index+1,
                module_name: module[index].moduleName,
                category: "test",
                actions: <div style={{display: "flex"}}>
                    <DeleteActionButton buttonLabel="Delete" onClick={() => changeModuleId("delete", 1)}/>
                    <UpdateActionButton buttonLabel="Update" onClick={() => changeModuleId("update", 1)} />
                </div>
            })
        }
        setModuleRows([...tempModuleRows])
    })
}, [])
```

when i try to access one of the element in the moduleRows, it's undefined
but when i try to change the declaration of the state to :

```
    const [moduleRows, setModuleRows] = React.useState([{}] as ModuleRow[]);
```

i can access index 0 of moduleRows, but i can't access index 1 and so on, then i try adding another { } in the array bracket, so my initialization looks like :

```
    const [moduleRows, setModuleRows] = React.useState([{}, {}] as ModuleRow[]);
```

now i can access index 0 and 1, but i can't access 2 and so on, but when i checking the length of moduleRows, it's exactly the same as the data fetched from the API

so i want to know why the empty array in the useState doesn't work and why using { } in the [ ] makes the program to read only as much as the { }

Comment: Try it like this: `React.useState<ModuleRow[]>([]);`

Comment: @Kapobajza i have tried, but the result was same as [ ]

Comment: What do you mean you can't access moduleRows[1]? There won't be any elements in your list on the first renders of this component.

Comment: @windowsill moduleRows[1] should be rendered after useEffect, and i can't access index 1 because the program reads only as much as { } exists in [ ] because i can access index 0 when intializing using [{ }]

Comment: That makes sense. If you initialize the state as [] it will initially have 0 elements. If you initialize it as [{}] it will have 1 element. Please, please show the rendering code so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the bug you are talking about. [Here is a working codesandbox.io demo.](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-orla-9p40u?file=/src/App.tsx)

```js
import { ReactNode, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { sleep } from "sleepjs";

type ModuleRow = {
  no: number;
  module_name: string;
  category: string;
  actions: ReactNode;
};

type Module = {
  moduleName: string;
};

const getModule: () => Promise<Module[]> = () => {
  const array: Module[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    array.push({
      moduleName: `Module ${i + 1}`
    });
  }
  return new Promise(async (res) => {
    await sleep(1000);
    return res(array);
  });
};

export default function App() {
  const [moduleRows, setModuleRows] = useState<ModuleRow[]>([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getModule().then((module: Module[]) => {
      let tempModuleRows: ModuleRow[] = [];
      for (let index = 0; index < module.length; index++) {
        tempModuleRows.push({
          no: index + 1,
          module_name: module[index].moduleName,
          category: "test",
          actions: (
            <div key={index} style={{ display: "flex" }}>
              {module[index].moduleName}
              <button>Update</button>
              <button>Delete</button>
            </div>
          )
        });
      }
      setModuleRows([...tempModuleRows]);
    });
  }, []);

  if (!moduleRows.length) return <div>Loading...</div>;
  return <>{moduleRows.map((m) => m.actions)}</>;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but when i apply this it doesn't work but it does give me a clue that the state does changed but the way i access the data is wrong

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, the problem is not how i initialize my state, but how i do access the state, i can access the state by using the map but when im call the state using index ([0], [1]) it does give an error